# Regex to extract data between two labels

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a file `svn_log.txt` with following data:

```
:SUMMARY: This module is test created
:TIME: the current time is not listed
```

I am using tcl and regex to extract summary from this file.

```
set svn_logs svn_logs.txt
set fp [open $svn_logs r]
set lines [split [read -nonewline $fp] "\n"]
close $fp
foreach line $lines {
    if {[regexp -nocase {^\s*(:SUMMARY)\s*:\s*(.*)$} $line match tag value]} {
        set [string tolower $tag] $value
    }
}
puts $value
```

It works fine until summary has only one line. But there are cases where summary has points:

```
:SUMMARY: Following changes needs to be added
1. this one
2. this one too
:TIME:
```

In this case, it doesn't extract anything other than the first line. I am having hard time trying to modify the above regex command to take anything between `:SUMMARY` and `:TIME`. New to regex. Can anyone provide any input?

original content of file ->

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r743 | aaddh | 2014-04-01 12:33:42 -0500 (Tue, 01 Apr 2014) | 8 lines

:SUMMARY: Modified file to add following changes:
1.Loop to avoid . 
2.Change directory 
3.The batch file
:TIME: Invalid
:Test:
:Comments:
```

Comment: Does your file contain only one `:SUMMARY:` and `:TIME:`?

Comment: It contains lot of things actually. But I am only concerned about :SUMMARY

Comment: But do you have multiple `:SUMMARY:`s?

Comment: No. There is only one :SUMMARY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a different approach if you really want to use regex. You will have to read the whole file at one go and use regex on it:

```
set svn_logs svn_logs.txt
set fp [open $svn_logs r]
set lines [read -nonewline $fp]
close $fp
regexp -nocase -lineanchor -- {^\s*(:SUMMARY)\s*:\s*(.*?):TIME:$} $lines match tag value
puts $value
```

With as input:

```
:SUMMARY: Following changes needs to be added
1. this one
2. this one too
:TIME:
```

You get:

```
Following changes needs to be added
1. this one
2. this one too
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/9PBMGxVM)

The `-lineanchor` flag makes `^` match all beginning of lines and `$` match all end of lines. `--` just makes sure that there are no extra flags.

Note: There's a lingering newline at the end of the captured group, you can trim it if required.

Comment: -> Its not working. There is a line above summary as well, and I guess that could cause the problem, is it?

Comment: @UnderDog That shouldn't be a problem. See [this other demo](http://codepad.org/UeA5lI8f). I inserted a line above `SUMMARY` in there.

Comment: @UnderDog There was a typo in my code. I had `lines` above and used `line` in the regexp. See if that fixes it?

Comment: I saw that problem in the beginning only. Thats not it. It is not filling up value. So somewhere it is not matching the characters. I cant paste the content of the file here because it will screw the formatting. Let me edit the question and add it thr

Comment: Added the original content of the file. I tried the regex on this one, but it doesnt recognize. I know thr is Module thr instead of TIME. I changed that too

Comment: In that case you don't need the final `$`.

Comment: Perfect! Jerry, thanks a lot for this help. But just a point of guide, if thr are multiple summaries, what would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend first extracting all the summaries first with the -inline flag into a list, then parse each element of the list.

Comment: I am really new to regex. But I will just try and google what you said. Thanks a ton for this input.

Comment: I cant thank you enough jerry. I was really struggling with it. You are AWESOME :D

Answer (score 1):

The regexp solution is very compact. If you're reading the lines of the file, you could do:

```
set fh [open file r]
set insumm false
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    switch -regex -- $line {
        {^:SUMMARY:} {set insumm true; set summary [string range $line 10 end]} 
        {^:\w+:} break
        default {if {$insumm} {append summary \n $line}}
    }
}
close $fh
```

Comment: But it also includes :MODULE and other labels which are not required.

Comment: Really? not in my testing. What is different in the content of the file compared to what's shown in the question?

Comment: I changed `[[:upper:]]+` to `\w+` since the labels are apparently not all uppercase.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like: `[^:SUMMARY:](.*)[^:TIME:]`